# How terminal operation in java 8 Stream API called intermediate operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In java 8, Intermediate Operation add the listener like they are mean for lazy processing and whenever any terminal operation is called then that terminal operation will call each of these listener one by one sequentially and finally terminal operation will prepare the result depending upon type of operations and close the stream. So I want to understand that how these listener is added and how terminal operation internally called these intermediate operations listener.

Example :-

```
List<String> countries= Arrays.asList("India","Austriala","America","Japan","England","Germany");

countries.stream().map(s -> s.length()).max(Integer :: compare).get();

Map<Integer,Set<String>> map = countries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, Collectors.toSet()));
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out :: println);
```

Here we are using one intermediate operation map and max is the terminal operation.

Comment: It's unclear what level of detail or what specifics you want. If you want "how it works internally" then just look at the OpenJDK source code, it's all quite visible. If you a more specific question, then maybe formulate this. As it stands your question could be answered by a whole book, which doesn't make it well-suited for a SO question.

Comment: I have gone through few links that simply talks about the fact that  it is the terminal operations which will call the listeners added by intermediate operations which is fine and understandable from birds eyes. But i am looking for more internal details like how these listeners are added and how terminal operation take care of calling these to complete the processing. If you have any idea about the same or if you can route to some nice link that also will be helpful

Comment: There are no listeners involved. Not every function is a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough: `countries` is a stream. `countries.map(s -> s.length())` creates a new object. This object contains 2 things:

- That stream
- The code `s -> s.length()` as a function.

That's all. It doesn't process the stream. It is, itself, a stream. If you ask this stream to provide data, it will start reading its inner stream, and tossing the objects that fall out of that inner stream at the function it has, then, it provides those.

Only the terminal op starts asking the stream you invoked the terminal on (the `X` in `X.max`) for data, which then 'sets the train in motion'. That X will start producing data, and in order to do so, assuming X is an intermediate, it will ask the Y that you called it on (The `Y` in `Y.map(s -> s.length())`, and so on.

Java's core libraries are all open source.

Comment: When you says that countries.map(s -> s.length()) will create a new object , is that means for each intermediate operations a new object will be created ?

Comment: Whether they create a new object, is up to the implementation. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) says, “*some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object*”. But in either case, the returned stream is the stream that has remembered that you invoked `map` with that function.

Comment: @Mukesh As per the spec, 'up to the implementation', but, generally, yes. If you are thinking: Oh no! The performance! Stop. Object creation has zero cost in the vast majority of cases. Computers (and performance, and hotspot) is vastly more complicated than that.